# Using include file method and a value is not getting set - php

Tags: php

So i am trying to recieve a value after a form is submitted to see if checkboxes where selected and if they wernt values would be changed in a file and another file would grab it and check to see if a value was set to display a "you need to select checkbox" message

here is code for the checkboxes-------------------

```
include 'checkvalidation.php';



            CODE

<form action="insert.php" method="post">

            <input type="checkbox" value"On" name="only-thisform"/>I will complete the insurance verification form only. 
            <?php 
             echo $setError;
            if ($setError == 1){

                echo "please Check box before continuing.";
            }
             ?>
            <br>
            <br>

            <input type="checkbox"  value="On" name="approval" id="approval"/>I agree to authorize PCG Protects, LLC to receive a certificate of liability and or to be added as an additional interest on my personal auto policy, whichever accommodates my Auto Insurance Carriers standard practice, so they can monitor the active status of my personal auto policy, on behalf of my employer.
             <?php 

             if ($setError == 1){
                echo "please Check box before continuing.";
             }

             ?>

            <br>
            <br>
  CODE

    </form>
```

Here is insert file

```
include 'checkvalidation.php';

CODE
    /***************************************VALIDATE CHECK BOXES ARE CHECKED *********************************************************/

            $ch1 = 'unchecked';
            $ch2 = 'unchecked';
        //  print_r("testing ch1 : $ch1");
            if(isset($_POST['only-thisform']))  {

                $ch1 = 'Check';
                //if ($setChecker != 1)
                $setError= 0;
                //print_r("testing ch1: $ch1");

            }
            if ($ch1 !='Check' ){

            $setError = 1;
            header("Location: test.php");
            exit;

        }
            if (isset($_POST['approval'])) {
                //$setChecker = 1;
                $ch2 = 'Check';
                $setError= 0;
                //print_r("testing  ch2: $ch2");
            }
             if ($ch2 != 'Check' ){

            $setError = 1;
            header("Location: test.php");
            exit;

        }
/***************************************************************************************************************************************/           

          CODE
```

Here is checkvalidation file -------------------

```
<?php 




             $setError = 0;


            echo $setError; 



?>
```

So pretty much i am trying to get a value that is changed during a form submission proccess so i can display a message as to why the form was not submitted

UPDATED ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**   $setError is always  0

Comment: chceck your include path with <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: Pass error flag in query string something like,   header("Location: test.php?error=1"); and then in your test.php check if($_GET['error']){$setError=0;}else $setError=1;

Comment: so (header("Location: test.php?setError=1") ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
$setError = 1;
header("Location: test.php");
```

$setError is not transport to test.php,you should find a way(get or post)to send it to test.php

Comment: header("Location: test.php?seterror=1"); then in test.php:$setError=$_GET['seterror'];

Comment: Oh my gosh something so simple goes right past me hehe :)  thank you so much man your the best in the midwest or anywhere else!  Blessing *10

Comment: oh cause where i am located its its midwest of united states :D